# NodeJS crypto verify.verify not working for ES256 P-256 JWT but same code works for RSA

Tags: node.js, jwt, elliptic-curve, verify

I am trying to write a "pure" NodeJS function that will verify the signature on a JSON Web Token as the environment I am deploying into does not have this package available.

The code works for none elliptic curve keys but not if I use P-256 and ES256 - I just get the annoyingly vague "false" from the NodeJS crypto verify.verfify function.

This is the function body:

```
function verifyToken(token, publicKey) {
    const [headerEncoded, payloadEncoded, signatureEncoded] = token.split('.')

    const payload = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(payloadEncoded, 'base64').toString())
    const verify = crypto.createVerify('sha256')
    verify.update(headerEncoded + '.' + payloadEncoded)
    
    const isValidSignature = verify.verify(publicKey, signatureEncoded, 'base64')
    if (!isValidSignature) {
        throw new Error('Invalid signature')
    }

    return payload
}
```

I am generating private and public keys in JWK format at this useful site: https://mkjwk.org/

I use jsonwebtoken to create the JWT and then compare my verify function against the jsonwebtoken version. I know I am using the private key in each case - but that is just to shorten the example.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const crypto = require('crypto')

function verifyToken(token, publicKey) {
    const [headerEncoded, payloadEncoded, signatureEncoded] = token.split('.')

    const payload = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(payloadEncoded, 'base64').toString())
    const verify = crypto.createVerify('sha256')
    verify.update(headerEncoded + '.' + payloadEncoded)
    
    const isValidSignature = verify.verify(publicKey, signatureEncoded, 'base64')
    if (!isValidSignature) {
        throw new Error('Invalid signature')
    }

    return payload
}

// Example RSA style key
const privateKey1 = {
    "key": {
        "p": "<redacted>",
        "kty": "RSA",
        "q": "<redacted>",
        "d": "<redacted>",
        "e": "AQAB",
        "use": "sig",
        "kid": "<redacted>",
        "qi": "<redacted>",
        "dp": "<redacted>",
        "alg": "RS256",
        "dq": "<redacted>",
        "n": "<redacted>"
    },
    "format": "jwk"
}

// Example ES256 - generated from https://mkjwk.org/
const privateKey2 = {
    "key": {
        "kty": "EC",
        "d": "<redacted>",
        "use": "sig",
        "crv": "P-256",
        "kid": "<redacted>",
        "x": "<redacted>",
        "y": "<redacted>",
        "alg": "ES256"
    },
    "format": "jwk"
}

var token1 = jwt.sign({ 'hello': 'world' }, privateKey1, 
    { 'algorithm' : privateKey1.key.alg, expiresIn: 60 * 60, 'header': { 'typ': 'JWT', 'alg' : privateKey1.key.alg } })

console.log('json web token  1 = ', jwt.verify(token1, privateKey1)) // This works
console.log('pure node token 1 = ', verifyToken(token1, privateKey1)) // This works

var token2 = jwt.sign({ 'hello': 'world' }, privateKey2, 
    { 'algorithm' : privateKey2.key.alg, expiresIn: 60 * 60, 'header': { 'typ': 'JWT', 'alg' : privateKey2.key.alg } })

console.log('json web token  2 = ', jwt.verify(token2, privateKey2)) // This works
console.log('pure node token 2 = ', verifyToken(token2, privateKey2)) // This fails
```

Are there other options that I need to give to verify.verify?

I have checked the tokens at https://jwt.io and the signature is good there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by an incompatible ECDSA signature format.

ECDSA signatures are mainly specified in two formats, IEEE P1363 and ASN.1/DER, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/57731):
In the context of JWT, P1363 is used by definition, see [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-3.4) (steps 1 to 4 describe P1363), i.e. the (Base64url encoded) signature in the generated token has the P1363 format.
The crypto module of NodeJS, on the other hand, uses ASN.1/DER by default, see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#verifyverifyobject-signature-signatureencoding) and [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatepublickeykey), but can be switched to P1363 via the property `dsaEncoding`. To do this, the key must be extended as follows:

```js
const privateKey2 = {
    "key": {
        "kty": "EC",
        "d": "v5PriRLFXqqILYFZkX2LWEbUQ_y_NCZXD6il5S6KPus",
        "use": "sig",
        "crv": "P-256",
        "kid": "f8124e12-98c4-4299-b93b-9d9a65f477db",
        "x":"r9FyRzL88VKR0wIhiDr8JFOTd5K_hVDb7uw0VDxOM7U",
        "y":"aqK5Wmb-UgjDPQ5cB1QGccATrtmgPDRnPzR5JCMPs_M",
        "alg": "ES256"
    },
    "format": "jwk",
    "dsaEncoding": "ieee-p1363" // switch to P1363
}
```

With this change, also the ECDSA signature is successfully verified.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes that fixed the script. I had been staring at the description of the dsaEncoding option in the Node JS documentation without comprehending the importance. I think that documentation could do with some more examples.

Comment: Hi @topaco do you know if this should work in NodeJS V14 (I know!). I get a "The "key.key" property must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received an instance of Object" on the verify.verify call. 

Was there a previous format for JWK in Node JS v14. The documentation doesn't appear to show any difference.

Comment: @NeilSkilling - In the documentation of [`createPrivateKey()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreateprivatekeykey) or [`createPublicKey()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatepublickeykey) it is described (s. *History*) that the JWK format is supported only as of v15.12.0. In earlier NodeJS versions PEM or DER encoded keys must be used (in PKCS#8 or SEC1 format for private EC keys and in X.509/SPKI format for public EC keys).